# How do I turn down GPU heat / usage on a Sony Vaio Z21?

Tags: power-management, overheating, vaio, sony

I have a Sony Vaio Z21 (VPC2) and am experiencing some GPU heat/usage issues since kernel 3.2 up till 3.9.

I have installed laptop-mode-tools, configured powertop and added the following to grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.semaphores=1"

This last line was found in a tutorial specific for this device, stated that it will provide better power management.

Doing all this managed to get back to 11.7w, measured while typing this post. But my device still keeps blowing out some heated air from the casing, and the fan keeps running. My device is new and therefore very clean and does not have this problem when running Windows.

I also experience this when connected to the PMD which contains a ATI graphics card.

Below is a screenshot of powertop, showing the GPU's active state while writing this post:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RujLc.png, Screenshot shows GPU active state of 92.8 procent

My questions:
- Do other users, with the same model, experience this as well?
- Are there ways for me to dial down the GPU usage as it now runs too hot?
- Is there something like the cpu governor, for GPU?

Comment: Thank you @Qasim. I will certainly take a look at this, probably tonight or tomorrow evening. I'll get back to you if this solved my issue.

Comment: @Qasim, I have the laptop-mode-tools installed, would this be of any conflict ? Should I, for best practice, remove that prior to the installation of TLP ?

Comment: @Qasim, Output of lspci: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09).

I said i have a ATI card in my docking station, in my laptop i have a intel video card. 

Temp: CPU temp               =    52 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)

Also, I find that using TLP actually makes my GPU go to 100% usage in Powertop. Laptop is heating up now.

Comment: I always dim my screen after booting. This 100% gpu usage was with a max of 25% of my screen brightness. I've noticed that all my tunables in powertop went bad again, and the overall power usage went from 11 to 13 watt, using tlp instead of laptop-mode-tools. Any sugestions?

Comment: Everything is on battery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8778/discussion-between-roberto-and-qasim)

Comment: @Qasim, or anyone else, got any further information or instructions for me?

Comment: Join the chat......& delete all the comments here

Comment: Sorry I cannot contribute much but I wanted to point out I get a lot head and fan noise as well and any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for ati card with open source driver two ways are there both can be also used

1. install the gnome shell extension for this u will have to switch to the gnome shell    which is worth to give a try the shell extension is \
   : raedon profile manager https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/356/radeon-power-profile-manager/

after installing this extension u need to set the profile to low from the icon of this extension at the top panel

2 if u r adamant to use unity try this :
Open your terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and open the Grub config file by using the following command:

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Now here search for this line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Replace the above line with this one and save the file:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"

Update the Grub by using this command:

sudo update-grub

if possible to use gnome shell use both the method it will surely decrease the temp i did this to solve my heating problem hope this works for u too